# how to make a circular line of sight in cocos2d tile map

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem about cocos2d tile maps.
My aim is to make a circular line of sight that when player moves around, it must only see its around in circle but not see the rest. I have tried many things and successed it in rectangular area but I couldn't succeed it in circular area.
I am waiting for your answers. 
Thanks for your help.
If you help me immidiately, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Use rectangular area and add an alpha mask with round gradient as a child of the player to make the visible part round.
E.g.
with fading

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3IEDI.png]

without fading

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Y90ZR.png]

Edit.

The green layer is the fog. Only a square of it is uncovered ("I have tried many things and successed it in rectangular area"). The red layer is the circular vision map. It covers some of the visible squares and so the user sees uncovered circle.

[image]

Comment: Can you give me a sample code about adding alpha mask Alexander? It doesn't make sense at me :)

Comment: Add an image with transparency (alpha mask) as a child to the player object (so it follows the movement). The dark parts will imitate fog, the transparent will show what's visible under the image.

Comment: `[playerObject addChild:transparencySprite];`

Comment: Actually alexander I am new to objective c programming. This is my first application in cocos2d.I don't know how to add an alpha mask. If you write this part of code, I will be appreciate. Thank you very much.

Comment: I just did, man. Alpha mask is nothing more than a sprite with transparency.

Comment: Alexander, yes I can add a transparent sprite there. But the thing I want to do is to make everywhere invisible when player does not go there. Like that:
https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/603b71089f0ab083dbc82dc304ba58ec5d96f68d/687474703a2f2f7338383338373234332e6f6e6c696e65686f6d652e75732f726d78702f666f675f6f665f7761722f666f675f6f665f7761722e6a7067


The only difference is I want this vision in circular area.
Thank you again for your patience.